# Getters & Setters in a prototype pattern

Tags: javascript, prototype, getter-setter

I'd like to use getters & setters within a prototype pattern. I did this by putting Object.defineProperty in the constructor.

I know that i can just create getWhatever() methods in the prototype object, by I like the brevity of accessing properties through real getters/setters

But having the defineProperty outside the prototype object like this doesn't feel right to me. Is there a better way?

```
function Person(name) {
    this._name = name;

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
        get: function() {
            return this._name;
        }
    });
}
```

the plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/h3tgJjQBGspepdho3lqJ?p=preview

Comment: Why not just define the getter to the prototype outside the constructor: `Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, 'name', {...});`

Comment: Consider also using `let _name` instead of `this._name` that way name wont be accessible to change outside your object :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it may belong on code review

Comment: Thats the only way I am aware of, Object.defineProperty is a very powerful way of creating object so better get used to it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do it on the prototype itself?

```
function Person(name){
    this._name = name;
}

Object.defineProperty( Person.prototype, 'name', {
    get:function(){ return this._name; }
})
```

Comment: Where is `this._name` defined?

Comment: But then cant a person do `personObject._name = 'blah'` to overwrite the name?

Comment: Of course they can, but this is JS, not a true object oriented language.  If a person sees a variable prefixed with an `_prop` and then overwrites it still without considering the implications, that's on them.  This is a pragmatic solution, not a perfect one.

Comment: Unfortunately, though, if you're using WebStorm to debug, the debugger panel won't show the getter value. Looks like it can't read the 'this' value inside the getter.

Comment: I use Webstorm as my IDE but I've never had any luck using it's debugger.  I think that's partially because we build our app with Browserify so it doesn't actually *know* about the running instance.  Plus we do everything with Coffeescript so I'm doubting it would be worth the effort for me to try to get it up and running.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 classes in combination with modules can be used to create true **private members** with **getters on the prototype**.

> The WeakMap object is a collection of key/value pairs in which the
>   keys are objects only and the values can be arbitrary values.-MDN

```
const _name = new WeakMap(); 

class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    _name.set(this, name); // Set key to THIS and value to name. 
  }

  // Members in class body are automatically on prototype.
  get name() {
    return _name.get(this); // Get value (name) via key (THIS).
  }
}

const p = new Person('Betti');

p.name;  // Betti
p.name = 'Toni';
p.name;  // Betti
```

To prevent access to the name WeakMap we can put it along with the person class in their own module (separate file called e.g. person.js). 
We then only export the class, thus the WeakMap cannot be accessed.

In person.js:

```
const _name = new WeakMap();

export class Person { ... }
```

And import it to wherever we need the class.

In script.js:

`import {Person} from './person';`

Workaround if not using Webpack:

add ".js" after person

```
import {Person} from './person.js';
```

and in our html file, change script type to "module"

```
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
```

(not sure if the workaround is advised in production, probably best to use Webpack)

Source: Moshes JS OOP course.